# Conditional expression requires all 3 expressions at the end

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
<div *ngFor="let f of layout?.photoframes; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
   <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="f.x" [style.border-color]="(selectedObject===f) ? 'red'"  />
</div>
```

the conditional style throws the error

> ```
> Conditional expression (selectedObject===f) ? 'red' requires all 3 expressions at the end
> of the expression [(selectedObject===f) ? 'red'] what can I do?
> ```

Comment: can't understand the downvotes

Comment: You had an error, you got an accurate message. Honestly I'm surprised this wasn't closed for having a typo.

Comment: @Daniel, you're using the "conditional operator", so you need (condition)?one-value:another value, in your case `[style.border-color]="(selectedObject===f) ? 'red':null"` . See that you use "null" to not put the style-border if the condition is not fullfilled. (NOTE: I also don't understand the downvotes)

Comment: That wasn't helpful, @CoreyOgburn.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need also to pass the result of the case in which condition will return `false`. In other words you need to pass correct [**ternary operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Something like `if/else`. If `true` return `red`, else return `blue`.

```
(selectedObject === f) ? 'red' : 'blue'
```

Answer (score 15):

This applies to a different context, but if you are using a pipe ( | ) in **Angular** and you get this error from your view you may need to put parentheses around your pipe like this:

```
<input value={{device.id ? (device.id | decimalToHex) : ''}}>
```

if you leave them off like this:

```
<input value={{device.id ? device.id | decimalToHex : ''}}>
```

Then you get this error

Answer (score -2):

Just remove the **'?'** sign from the **"layout?.photoframes"**.