# During updating from Angular 11 to 12 I get Parser Error: Conditional expression min ?? null requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, input, eslint, mat-input

I have a problem after updating to angular 12 from angular 11 the whole project is red with errors in VS Code wherever I'm using input type="number" with min = "1" and [(ngModel)].

The error is

```
Parser Error: Conditional expression min ?? null requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression [min ?? null] in ...
Parser Error: Unexpected token ? at column 6 in [min ?? null] in ...
```

So for example this line is the problem:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width margin-left-10 ">
<input matInput class="form-control textarea-border" type="number"
                      style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center; "
                      min="0"
                      [(ngModel)]="model.OdvagaPrva"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

- If I remove min="0" line then I don't get this error
- If I put type="text" then I don't get this error
- If I remove ngModel line then I don't get this error

[image]

Edited: mat-form-field tag

Comment: can you please provide a stackblitz?

Comment: Don't know how since I'm using mat-form-field I can't import MatFormFieldModule in stackblitz...

Comment: you have to add material package in package.json

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-xmznld?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

I've added it but it doesn't work...Also I've copied every dependency from my package.json to stackblitz package.json

Comment: I believe the error is not in this line. its somewhere else. because it works for me in stackblitz :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-input-xflhrr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fstyles.css

Comment: This type of error generally comes in case of ternary operator :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571252/conditional-expression-requires-all-3-expressions-at-the-end